# Difference between using constructor + function vs function with parameters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I am very new to programming and I have a very basic question...
What's the difference between using constructor values in a function vs using parameters in a function?

Let's say there's a class called `Add`

```
class Add {
  constructor(number1, number2){
    this.number1 = number1;
    this.number2 = number2;
  }

  addNumbers (number1, number2){
    return number1 + number2;
  }

  addNumbersWithConstructor (){
    return this.number1 + this.number2;
  }
}
```

Both `addNumbers` and `addNumbersWithConstructor` do the same thing.

```
const AdditionMaker = new Add(1,2);
const result1 = AdditionMaker.addNumbers(3,2)
const result2 = AdditionMaker.addNumbersWithConstructor()
console.log(`result1 is ${result1}`) //5
console.log(`result2 is ${result2}`) //3
```

What's the difference between `addNumbers` and `addNumbersWithConstructor`?

Comment: `addNumbersWithConstructor` reads `AdditionMaker`'s internal properties whereas `addNumbers` does not.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between the two methods addNumbers and addNumbersWithConstructor is the way they handle the input parameters.

addNumbers takes two parameters number1 and number2 as arguments, which are not the same as the instance properties this.number1 and this.number2. In other words, addNumbers ignores the instance properties and just performs a simple addition of the two arguments passed in.

On the other hand, addNumbersWithConstructor does not take any arguments and instead uses the instance properties this.number1 and this.number2 that were set in the constructor when the instance of Add was created.

So when you call result1 = AdditionMaker.addNumbers(3, 2), you're passing 3 and 2 as arguments which get added together to give a result of 5.

When you call result2 = AdditionMaker.addNumbersWithConstructor(), you're not passing any arguments but instead the method is using the values of this.number1 and this.number2 which were set to 1 and 2 respectively when the instance was created. Therefore, the method returns 3, which is the result of adding 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! What's the best practice though? Is it always better to code as `addNumbersWithConstructor`, so that we don't ignore the constructor values?

Comment: Yeah, a constructor allows you to initialize the values, upon variable creation, so always a go-go

Comment: It all depends if you want the `Add` class to keep track of those numbers. In this case I see no benefit to do that, so a function with arguments is better.